# Is PAE worth it when I have 4GB RAM?

Tags: linux, kernel, pae, i386

I have 4GB RAM installed on my machine, and I'm considering using all of it (IE, installing PAE-enabled kernel). I heard there's a performance penalty for this, so I wanted to know about other's experiences. Should I proceed, or should I remain content with 3GB?

[**note**] I will be running **Linux 2.6.32**.

Comment: what is your current memory usage? and what kinds of applications are you running? ones that will use more memory if they have it? e.g. postgres

Comment: @xeno __top__ claims that I'm having 200MB RAM available, and 1.6GB cached. That's roughly when I'm running __Windows VirtualBox__, __Firefox__, and 3 Java apps (__Eclipse__, __Oracle SQL Developer__, and __Mule__).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a 64-bit processor, an alternative would be to try a 64-bit kernel.

According to [this RedHat white paper](http://people.redhat.com/nmurray/RHEL-2.1-VM-whitepaper.pdf), a typical server experiences around 1% performance hit, and other tasks suffered a performance hit of 0% - 10%.

In addition to having more available memory, enabling PAE means you have an NX bit, which can increase security.

Comment: But a 64-bit kernel has problems of its own, such as compatibility. I suggest you try out the different options and see which one feels best.